# Using ioctl communication between Kernel mode and user mode

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, kernel-module, ioctl

I want to communicate with my kernel module using ioctl. I have written two c program one for kernel module and other for user mode. I am getting this error while compiling kernel module:

error: unknown field ‘ioctl’ specified in initializer

at this line :

```
struct file_operations Fops = {
 .read = device_read,
 .write = device_write,
 .ioctl = device_ioctl,  ------> at this point error is occuring.
 .open = device_open,
 .release = device_release,
};
```

any idea why this is happening.

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In newer kernels, the preferred way is to use `.unlocked_ioctl` or `.compat_ioctl` fields. The plain `.ioctl` was removed from `struct file_operations`. [This discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/what-is-the-difference-between-ioctl-unlocked-ioctl-and-compat-ioctl) may clarify what happened and how to deal with that.

Answer (score 4):

In newer kernels, use `.unlocked_ioctl` in the place of  `.ioctl`. It works fine.